# Почему можно и нужно игнорировать папку Library при работе с (VCS, т.е. системой контроля версий)?

Tags: unity3d

Library – локальный кэш для импортируемых Assets узнаю я в этой [статье](https://habr.com/ru/post/250711/)

Затем я узнаю что эту папку можно и нужно прописывать в .gitignore при работе с VCS. Звучит заманчиво, учитывая что папка по весу представляет из себя 70-80% моего Unity проекта.

Library играет свою роль, не до конца понимаю какую, но не просто так она в проекте же. Что будет если я клонирую репозиторий игры где нет Library? Не полетит ли всё к чертям?

Comment: вы можете ее хоть каждый день стирать, ничего к чертям не полетит. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88#%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего не полетит только по одной причине: если её нет, то при запуске Юнити он сам создаёт эту папку и наполняет служебными и кэшируемыми данными.

А стоит её поместить в игнор как минимум по одной причине: папка может весить существенно (ну например 300Мб) и другим людям тянуть такие данные из гита нет никакой нужды, т.к. они могут быть сгенерированы у них на стороне самостоятельно. В итоге вы просто облегчите изнь другим разрабам, которым не придётся тянуть столько ненужных данных.  Причём те, что были сгенерированы под вашу систему под вашу работу, а не под их